# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function [REACT]

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the router.js file I have this:

```
const Offices = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./modules/Offices/views/Offices"),
  loading: Loading,
});

 { path: "/offices", name: "Offices", component: Offices },
```

Running in local I have no problem, it works, but after build and then deploying on server (dockerized) I receive the following exception:

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
> at index.browser.js:117:1
> at index.browser.js:116:1
> at 869 (index.browser.js:115:1)
> at n (index.browser.js:1466:1)
> at 579 (index.browser.js:10:1)
> at n (index.browser.js:1466:1)
> at index.browser.js:1495:6
> at 432 (index.browser.js:7:1)
> at s ((index):1:1494)
> at 200 (officeService.js:18:34) j @ routes.js:7

I am struggling about it. Can you help please?